# How to properly put table record value to jquery function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, function

In my php code i have this stroke:

```
echo "<td><button id='pausebut_{$record['idTrack']}' name='StopButton' 
type='Button' value='{$record['PreviewURL']}'>Stop</button>
</td>";
```

I output a table and for each row I create a button with a unique ID. I want to create a simple Jquery function:

```
$('??????').hide();
```

But instead of question marks there must be an ID `(pausebut_{$record['idTrack']})`. How should I put it in a proper way?

Comment: Send the actual value of the ID as a string to the front-end, which jQuery can then grab and create a dynamic element with that id.

Comment: question is not clear? you want to hide all button or specific-one?

Comment: Hide what and based on what condition? Please take some time to read [ask]

Comment: Hide all buttons by their id. It's just for understanding a syntax. Then I will use it in more complex task

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! **We are not a code writing service.** Please show us what you have tried, and detail what the problem is. Also, learn how to ask good questions for more tips.

Comment: I have tried lots of things. For example this code works well: $('#pausebut_1').hide(); $('#pausebut_2').hide(); etc...But I don't know how to put dynamic id properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Note, it would be better to have a class assigned to each button. Such as 'pauseButtonClass' then your code looks like this:

`$('.pauseButtonClass').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).id();
  //do with it what you want.
});`

Comment: `$('StopButton')` looks for an element `<StopButton>` that clearly doesn't exist

Comment: I just changed it and had it refer to a class. I haven't had enough caffeine yet today. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("button[name='StopButton']").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#' + id).hide();
});
```

Comment: Yes, thank You, but this a bit wrong. Event should not work onclick.

Comment: @Galat91 Check this jsfiddle for reference https://jsfiddle.net/bn5sfgst/1/

Comment: @Shiladitya Thank You. Will try to understand how it works.